# Is it better to store data as "60 * 60 * 24" or 86400

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code exactly:

```
static constexpr uint32_t secondsInADay = 60 * 60 * 24;
static constexpr uint32_t secondsInAnHour = 60 * 60;
static constexpr uint32_t secondsInAMinute = 60;
```

Would it be faster/efficient to store it like this:

```
static constexpr uint32_t secondsInADay = 86400;
static constexpr uint32_t secondsInAnHour = 3600;
static constexpr uint32_t secondsInAMinute = 60;
```

Or will it just be the same? Will it also use more memory?

Comment: It's a compile-time operation, it will be calculated before the assembly/executable is generated.

Comment: Build both (with optimizations enabled) and take a look at the generated assembly to compare the two. [The compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) is very useful for this.

Comment: that might solve you're question, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Comment: i guess thats not what the question is about, but you should rather write `secondsInAminute = 60; secondsInAnHour = 60*secondsInAMinute; secondsInADay = secondsInAnHour = 24 * secondsInAnHour;` (maybe even with named constants for `mintuesPerHour, HoursPerDay`)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: With `std::chrono`, you might even avoid *"magic"* numbers completely ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 indeed, though also in general magicity can be reduced by named constants, even when they are only used to initialize another named constant. For minutes/hours/seconds your answer is a nice way to remove any magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constants are completely hardcoded, i.e. you assign them an explicit value in the code, which allows the compiler to compute the value at compile time.

`60*60*24` is *exactly* the same as `86400`

if you declare variables as:

```
uint32_t a = 60*60*24;
uint32_t b = 86400;
```

the assembly will have the following definitions:

```
a:
        .long   86400
b:
        .long   86400
```

tested with gcc.

Comment: Thanks! Will use the first one.

Comment: if you have `constexpr`, the compiler tries to compute the expression at compile time. You can also generate arrays at compile time this way :)

Comment: `60*60*24` will not be the same as 86400 if `int` is a 16-bit type

Answer (score 4):

Both are similar.

You can even do (to drop *"magic"* numbers):

```
static constexpr uint32_t secondsInADay =
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::days(1)).count();// C++20
//  std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::hours(24)).count();
static constexpr uint32_t secondsInAnHour =
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::hours(1)).count();
static constexpr uint32_t secondsInAMinute =
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::minutes(1)).count();
```

or

```
template <typename Duration>
constexpr auto numberOfSeconds(const Duration& duration)
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(duration).count();
}

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
static constexpr uint32_t secondsInADay = numberOfSeconds(24h);
                               // = numberOfSeconds(std::chrono::days(1));// C++20
static constexpr uint32_t secondsInAnHour = numberOfSeconds(1h);
static constexpr uint32_t secondsInAMinute = numberOfSeconds(1m);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are same. The expression will be calculated by compiler.

Please use the first one because it has more meaning.

Answer (score 1):

They're the same. There won't be any performance change because you declared them `constexpr`. They will, therefore, be computed during the compilation and replaced by their exact values in the assembly code.